# SQL Average Incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which returns

```
Rate
------
4
6
8


SELECT Rate FROM t_Vote 
EXCEPT 
SELECT MAX(Rate) FROM t_Vote 
EXCEPT 
SELECT MIN(Rate) FROM t_Vote
```

My aim is to get the average of those 3 numbers so I just need to replace the first `SELECT Rate` with `SELECT AVG(Rate)`. But instead of getting **6** the value that I get with `SELECT AVG(Rate)` is **5**.  Why is this like this? And When I try to `SELECT AVG(CAST(Rate AS FLOAT))`, it doesn't consider the EXCEPT condition.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My aim is to get the average of those 3 numbers so I just need to replace the first SELECT Rate with SELECT AVG(Rate)

You should do like below

```
:with cte(n)
as
(
SELECT Rate FROM t_Vote 
EXCEPT 
SELECT MAX(Rate) FROM t_Vote 
EXCEPT 
SELECT MIN(Rate) FROM t_Vote
)
select avg(n) from cte
```

Comment: Note that EXCEPT removes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`EXCEPT` solution will remove duplicates before calculating the average!

Simply remove max and min manually, and then calculate the average:

```
select (sum(Rate) - max(Rate) - min(Rate)) / (count(Rate) - 2)
from t_Vote
```

**Warning:** Will only work if there are at least 3 rows in the table!

Perhaps you'll need to multiply the sum with 1.0 to get float result? (Required by some dbms products, but not by others.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the average. You just need to run below query.

```
SELECT AVG(Rate) from t_vote
```

There is no need to write other two lines that have EXCEPT on it. I tested the above scenario and it is working properly in my machine(SQL 2008). Now the problem could be there are also other records in table which you don't want to include in average calculation such as 0, max value or min value. If so make sure you exclude those values as below. In below example I just excluded max value and min value.

```
Select AVG(Rate) from (
 SELECT Rate from t_vote
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT MAX(Rate) FROM t_Vote 
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT MIN(Rate) FROM t_Vote
)a
```

Comment: Obviously there's a reason why the except is there.. and read the details right after the code

Comment: Not just duplicates.. but removes the data that satisfies the following statement